# $M+Ra$ is a subring of $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with a unit and let $R\vartriangleright M$ be a maximal ideal prove that the group $M+Ra=\{m+ra\mid m\in M,r\in R\}$ is a subring of $R$.   $\quad a\in R$

*Attempt:*

I think I should check:

$1.\quad M+Ra\neq \emptyset$

$2.\quad m_1+r_1a_1-(m_2+r_2a_2)\in M+Ra$

$3.\quad (m_1+r_1a_1) (m_2+r_2a_2)\in M+Ra$

for 1: not empty because the unit is there

for 2: $(m_1-m_2+r_1a_1-r_2a_2)\in M+Ra$

for 3: $m_1m_2+m_1r_2a_2+r_1a_1m_2\overset{?}\in M+Ra$

Comment: for 3 note that $M$ is an ideal.

Comment: What are $a_1$ and $a_2$?

Comment: elements from the ring @celtschk

Comment: But isn't $a$ supposed to be a *constant* element in the definition of $M+Ra$?

Comment: @celtschk tell you the truth they didn't say nothing about $a$ in the exercise, its my geuss that $a$ is some element from the ring

Comment: Yes, it's *one* element of the ring. Namely the element used to define whar $M+Ra$ is.

Comment: Something still seems odd. If $a\in M$ then $M+Ra=M$, and otherwise $M+Ra=R$ (maximality of $M$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to be using a fixed $a$ not just arbitrary $a$'s for each element in the proposed ring. So the computation in #3 should run $(m_1+r_1a) (m_2+r_2a)=m_1m_2+a(m_2r_2+m_2r_1+r_1r_2a)\in M+Ra$. And of course the computation in #2 should be $m_1+r_1a-(m_2+r_2a)=(m_1+m_2)+a(r_1+r_2)\in M+Ra$

In the most general sense of "subring," this is a subring (a subgroup of $(R,+)$ which is closed under multiplication.) But note that it may or may not have an identity, and even if it does have an identity it does not have to share the same identity as $R$

Examples:

For any commutative nonzero ring $R$ with identity and $a\in M$, if $M$ is a summand of $R$ then $M+Ra=M$ is a subring with an identity different from $R$.  If $M$ isn't a summand, then $M$ is a subring without an identity.

Actually this question seems to be written a bit misleadingly (right now)... if $a\notin M$ then $M+Ra=R$, so there really isn't any other case then $M$ and $R$ being under consideration.

Answer (score 1):

The set $$Ra=\{ra\;|\;r\in R\}$$ where $a$ is a fixed element of $R$, forms a principal ideal of $R$ and so for a (maximal) ideal $M$,  $M+Ra$ is also an ideal of $R$. For this ideal to be a subring, it must have unit element $1$ which is not possible unless $M+Ra$ is the ring $R$ itself. So if $M+Ra$ is a subring of $R$ then it must be the whole ring $R$ itself.