# if $a\notin M$ so $R=M+Ra$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with a unit and let $R\vartriangleright M$ be a maximal ideal the group $M+Ra=\{m+ra\mid m\in M,r\in R\}$ is a subring of $R$.   $\quad a\in R$
>
> Prove that if $a\notin M$ so $R=M+Ra$

I really have no idea why this is true, maybe the unit is in the ideal so the ideal is the whole ring?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you ask [essentially the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2233794/mra-is-a-subring-of-r) twice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$M+Ra$ is a subring of $R$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2233794/mra-is-a-subring-of-r)

Comment: The previous is to prove that M+Ra is a subring, here its something else

Comment: You should read the questions more carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $M \subseteq M + Ra$. So if $a\notin M$, M is properly contained in the ideal $M + Ra$ but M is a maximal ideal so $R = M + Ra$.